# Сравнение дат из двух таблиц SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Прошу помощи в понимании какими методами я могу решить следующую задачу:

Есть таблица с колонками:
ID запроса, время начала выполнения запроса, время окончания выполнения запроса, часы затраченные на выполнения запроса (DATEDIFF двух предыдущих колонок)

Пример строки: 82735; 2018-03-26 10:13:13.177; 2018-04-09 11:08:13.070; **337**

Есть таблица со всеми выходными и праздничными днями за несколько лет:

Пример: 2017-01-01 00:00:00.000

Мне необходимо откорректировать колонку с часами с учетом, что запрос не обрабатывается в выходные и праздничные дни. Т.е. когда в интервал выполнения запроса выпадает выходной или праздничный день из таблицы, то из нее вычитаются 24*x часов, где x - количество дней из второй таблицы,которые выпадают на интервал запроса.

Пример откорректированной таблицы: 82735; 2018-03-26 10:13:13.177; 2018-04-09 11:08:13.070; **241** (337-24*4)

Благодарю за любую помощь

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Замените последний `SELECT` на `UPDATE`, ну и таблицы/поля само собой:

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE (
    Id      INT,
    StartTime   DATETIME,
    EndTime     DATETIME,
    Duration    INT
)

DECLARE @Holidays TABLE (
    Holiday DATETIME PRIMARY KEY
)

INSERT @Test (Id, StartTime, EndTime, Duration)
SELECT 1, '2018-03-26 10:13:13.177', 
    '2018-04-09 11:08:13.070',
    DATEDIFF(HH, '2018-03-26 10:13:13.177', '2018-04-09 11:08:13.070')
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '2017-03-26 10:13:13.177', 
    '2017-04-09 11:08:13.070',
    DATEDIFF(HH, '2017-03-26 10:13:13.177', '2017-04-09 11:08:13.070')

INSERT @Holidays
VALUES
    ('2018-03-29 00:00:00.000'),
    ('2018-04-01 00:00:00.000'),
    ('2018-04-02 00:00:00.000')


SELECT t.*, t.Duration - ISNULL(h.HolidaysCount, 0)*24 AS NewDuration, HolidaysCount
FROM @Test t
    OUTER APPLY(
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS HolidaysCount
        FROM @Holidays
        WHERE Holiday BETWEEN t.StartTime AND t.EndTime
    ) h
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!